# State values passed in as arguments in useEffect not being read in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, callback, lodash

I am trying to build a cryptocurrency application. But I am having trouble getting populated state values that are passed into the useEffect as parameters to a debouncing/polling function.

The issue is that the debouncing works well, as in it detects the value and calls the api after the 500ms that I specified in debounce. However, the polling portion seems to not have the state values of of `transactionType, fromCurrencyAmount`, and `pair`. It seems like after I debounce the input, after 6 seconds the polling will do its thing but the values passed in the params are undefined. Is there anyway I can solve this?

Here is the method that serves two purposes. It has an api to be polled from every 6 seconds, as well as getting debounced input if the user enters an amount inside the input.

```
  function handleInitPoll(baseAndQuote, side, value) {
    getSwapPrice(baseAndQuote, side, value || 0)
      .then((res) => {
        if (!res.price) {
          setIsLoading(true);
        } else if (res.error) {
          setErrorMessage(res.error);
        } else if (res.price) {
          setIsLoading(false);
          setSwapPriceInfo(res);
        }
      });
  }
```

And here is the useEffect:

```
  useEffect(() => {

      handleInitPoll(pair, transactionType, fromCurrencyAmount);

      const timer = setInterval(handleInitPoll, 6000, pair, transactionType, fromCurrencyAmount);
      return () => {
        clearInterval(timer);
      };
    }
    setSelectedCurrencyState({ ...selectedCurrencyState, selectedFromCurrency: 'USDT', selectedToCurrency: 'XLM' });
  }, [pair, transactionType, fromCurrencyAmount]);
```

And here is the debounce declaration:

```
  const debounceOnChange = useCallback(debounce(handleInitPoll, 500, pair, transactionType, fromCurrencyAmount), []);
```

And here is where the debouncing is being done, which is inside an onChange handler:

```
  const handleAssetAmount = (e) => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    const formattedAmount = handleAssetAmountFormat(value);
    setFromCurrencyAmount(formattedAmount);
    validateInputAmount(formattedAmount);
    debounceOnChange(pair, transactionType, formattedAmount);
  };
```

Comment: What's going on with the extra `setSelectedCurrencyState` after the `useEffect` hook's callback's return? This seems like an error.

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

The issue here is that you've closed over stale values in the interval callback.

## Solution

One solution is to cache these state values in a React ref such that the current value can be accessed in the polling function.

Example:

```
const pairRef = React.useRef(pair);
const transactionTypeRef = React.useRef(transactionType);
const fromCurrencyAmountRef = React.useRef(fromCurrencyAmount);

useEffect(() => {
  pairRef.current = pair;
}, [pair]);

useEffect(() => {
  transactionTypeRef.current = transactionTypeRef;
}, [transactionType]);

useEffect(() => {
  fromCurrencyAmountRef.current = fromCurrencyAmount;
}, [fromCurrencyAmount]);

useEffect(() => {
  handleInitPoll(pair, transactionType, fromCurrencyAmount);

  const timer = setInterval(() => {
    handleInitPoll(
      pairRef.current,
      transactionTypeRef.current,
      fromCurrencyAmountRef.current
    );
  }, 6000);

  return () => {
    clearInterval(timer);
  };
}, [pair, transactionType, fromCurrencyAmount]);
```

Comment: Hey @Drew Reese, thanks for your input! The values are no longer undefined but it is not polling anymore. But the debouncing works

Comment: @Kimbo It may be that having the dependencies affects the `useEffect` hook and setting the polling interval. Can you edit a more complete and comprehensive [mcve] in your post?

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally, your code seems to be correct with a few issues:

1. There is a race condition.

   If `getSwapPrice` is running and the component is updated, it can still
   affect the state when `setSwapPriceInfo` or `setLoading` are called when
   the promise is resolved.

   This is particularly bad, because network requests can "overtake" each
   other.  Thus it can happen that the return value of `getSwapPrice`
   updates the component with the result of an old network request.

   [This is discussed in this article.](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/#speaking-of-race-conditions)
2. There is this odd call to `setSelectedCurrencyState` in the `useEffect`
   block.  It's not clear what this is supposed to do, but it clearly doesn't
   belong there.

However, the underlying application should work fine, I reproduced it with a simpler application here:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function fetchExchangeRateAsync(multiplier) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(Math.random() * multiplier);
        }, 100);
    });
}

function CurrencyExchangeRate() {
    const [exchangeRate, setExchangeRate] = useState(null);
    const [inputValueString, setInputValueString] = useState("");

    const inputValue = Number(inputValueString);

    const [multiplier, setMultiplier] = useState(1.0);

    let outputValue = null;
    if (!isNaN(inputValue) && exchangeRate !== null) {
        outputValue = inputValue * exchangeRate;
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        // To avoid race conditions, we must not update the state from an asynchronous operation if
        // the component was re-rendered since then.
        //
        // https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/
        let didCancel = false;

        // Do not delay the first request.
        fetchExchangeRateAsync(multiplier)
            .then(newExchangeRate => {
                if (!didCancel) {
                    setExchangeRate(newExchangeRate);
                }
            });
        
        // Poll exchange rate.
        let intervalHandle = setInterval(() => {
            fetchExchangeRateAsync(multiplier)
                .then(newExchangeRate => {
                    if (!didCancel) {
                        setExchangeRate(newExchangeRate);
                    }
                });
        }, 500);

        return () => {
            didCancel = true;
            clearInterval(intervalHandle);
        };
    }, [multiplier]);

    return (
        <div>
            <input value={inputValueString} onChange={event => setInputValueString(event.target.value)} /><br />
            <p>With current exchange rate: {outputValue !== null ? outputValue : "(loading)"}</p>
            <button onClick={() => setMultiplier(100.0)}>Set Multiplier</button>
        </div>
    );
}

function App() {
    return (
        <CurrencyExchangeRate />
    );
}

export default App;
```

This is quite a bit different from what you are doing but it does demonstrate that your code should generally work:

- It is possible to trigger the fetch logic by changing the input field (here without debouncing) or in a given interval.
- The fetch logic runs immediately when the component is rendered for the first time.
- The "Set Multiplier" button can affect the value of `multiplier` and this information arrives in the `setInterval` call correctly.

  This works because `[multiplier]` dictates that the effect should be re-run if that variable changes.  When this happens, the old interval is first cleared with `clearInterval` and then re-started with `setInterval`.

  In your case that would be `pair`, `transactionType` and `fromCurrencyAmount` instead of `multiplier`.

**In other words, your issue seems to be outside the code that you provided in the question.**